# Fading an element onfocus and onblur

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a single word counter on the page that counts the number of characters for each input element.

When an input element is focused, a `fadeIn` function is triggered to fade in the counter element. When the input element loses focus i.e. is blurred, a `fadeOut` function is triggered on the counter.

However when you focus and blur the elements several times and in fast intervals with either the mouse or the keyboard, the fade effect is noticed less and less. The counter which fades in and out ends up only blinking between opacity: 0 and 1. A page refresh is required to achieve the fade effect again, until it screws up again.

This problem is also triggered if you tab through all elements and regain your initial focus on the browser address bar.

Why does this happen? Could it have something to do with the fade function and `setInterval`?

Here's an example fade function I use from http://www.scriptiny.com :

```
var fadeEffect=function(){
return{
    init:function(id, flag, target){
        this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
        clearInterval(this.elem.si);
        this.target = target ? target : flag ? 100 : 0;
        this.flag = flag || -1;
        this.alpha = this.elem.style.opacity ? parseFloat(this.elem.style.opacity) * 100 : 0;
        this.si = setInterval(function(){fadeEffect.tween()}, 20);
    },
    tween:function(){
        if(this.alpha == this.target){
            clearInterval(this.elem.si);
        }else{
            var value = Math.round(this.alpha + ((this.target - this.alpha) * .05)) + (1 * this.flag);
            this.elem.style.opacity = value / 100;
            this.elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
            this.alpha = value
        }
    }
}
}();
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery for this? it will be up to 10 strings..

Comment: Sure, I could see if the issue repeats itself in jQuery. But the reason I asked in the first place is to get a better understanding of why such things happen.

Comment: posted the jQuery sample, if understand your question correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you're not doing `clearInterval()` properly.  You are setting the interval like this:

```
this.si = setInterval();
```

but clearing the interval like this:

```
clearInterval(this.elem.si)
```

Shouldn't they both be `this.si` or both be `this.elem.si`?

Also, how are you invoking `fadeEffect`?  Are you using `new fadeEffect()`?  Are you sure that `this` is being handled properly when you call methods?

Comment: It turns out the interval needed to be assigned to this.elem.si, the actual element in question. Not to turn this into a forum discussion, but, why would setting the interval to the element differ than assigning it to a variable?

Comment: It would probably work either way as long as you read and write from the same item.  But, reading from one and writing to another meant you were never clearing the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery probably you are looking for such behaviour:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#test').fadeTo('fast', 0.5); // to set default opacity. CSS can be used here
        $('#test').focus(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        }).blur(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        });
    });
```

here is live example: http://jsfiddle.net/hrzw7/1/

if you have a lot of such controls, use `.class` selector: http://jsfiddle.net/hrzw7/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your examples Samich! You introduced some new ideas in never thought of.